# change buildpack of the application pushed to pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, buildpack

Is it possible to change the buildpack of the application pushed to pivotal cloud foundry, without pushing the application again? If there is a way, please tell me how or point me to a reference.

Comment: A buildpack change wouldn't take affect until you re-stage the app (that's what a buildpack does - decide how the app gets staged). Are you just trying to avoid uploading the app bits again? The cf CLI and most other clients do resource matching for upload avoidance (see http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/253/resource_match/list_all_matching_resources.html) so "cf push" doesn't actually re-upload everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it with the `cf push` commands (it will insist on uploading your app), but would assume you can call the relevant API directly:
`cf curl -X PUT /v2/apps/<app_guid> -d '{ "buildpack": "other-buildpack" }'`, followed by a `cf restage <your-app>`.
http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/253/apps/updating_an_app.html